# Sum of links neighbors in a graph

Tags: optimization, python

I'm trying to model this constraint in an optimization problem using Pulp and NetworkX. Here is a piece of code I'm using.

```
import pulp 
import networkx as nx

g = nx.Graph() 

links = [(1,2),(1,4),(1,5),(2,5),(2,3),(3,5),(3,4),(4,5)] 

g.add_edges_from(links)

#The problem
prob = pulp.LpProblem("MinimumSetVertexCover", pulp.LpMinimize)

# The variables
y = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("y", g.nodes(), cat=pulp.LpBinary)
z = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("z", g.edges(), cat=pulp.LpBinary)

#The objective function

for (u,v) in g.edges():
    prob += pulp.lpSum(y) + pulp.lpSum(z)

#The constraints
for (u,v) in g.edges():
    prob += z[(u,v)] <= y[v]
    prob += z[(u,v)] <= 1-y[u]
for v in g.nodes():
    prob +=  pulp.lpSum([z[(u,v)] for v in g.neighbors(u)]) >= 2*(1-y[v])    

prob.solve()
```

The optimizer throws this error          `---> 55     prob +=  pulp.lpSum([z[(u,v)] for v in g.neighbors(u)]) >= 2*(1-y[v]) KeyError: (5, 1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are trying to call `z[(5,1)]`, while your variable is `z[(1,5)]`. Also `u` and `v` are mixed up in the last constraint.

You can try:

```
for v in g.nodes():
    prob +=  pulp.lpSum([z[(u,v)] for u in g.neighbors(v) if (u,v) in z]) + pulp.lpSum([z[(v,u)] for u in g.neighbors(v) if (v,u) in z]) >= 2*(1-y[v])
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but this repeats the same output for the whole set of nodes. while the neighbors of a node should be different from the other nodes

Comment: You mean the same error is thrown ? Can you show the exact error ? Try the above code that I have edited.

Comment: No, It does not throw an error but the output is out of logic
 
_C17: 2 x_1 + z_(1,_5) + z_(2,_5) + z_(4,_5) + z_(5,_3) >= 2


_C18: 2 x_2 + z_(1,_5) + z_(2,_5) + z_(4,_5) + z_(5,_3) >= 2


_C19: 2 x_4 + z_(1,_5) + z_(2,_5) + z_(4,_5) + z_(5,_3) >= 2

_C20: 2 x_5 + z_(1,_5) + z_(2,_5) + z_(4,_5) + z_(5,_3) >= 2

_C21: 2 x_3 + z_(1,_5) + z_(2,_5) + z_(4,_5) + z_(5,_3) >= 2

It is the same constraint for every node.

Comment: $u$ and $v$ were mixed up. Retry the exact code in the answer

Comment: Thank you so much @ Kuifje, this solves the error.